# Using ansible configuration to ssh to a remote host

Tags: ssh, ansible

Is there  a way to use ansible's configuration (mostly the hosts file), to ssh to the nodes, doing somethings like:

```
ansible ssh worker1
```

In a similar fashion to what **vagrant** does.
I've looked around both in the help and a bit over the documentation but I don't seem to find a way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I see the reasoning, I am familiar with "vagrant ssh". If you look at vagrant, you will see that there is another command, "vagrant ssh-config", that gives you an SSH configuration file you can then use it with "ssh -F config.tmp ...". Try it, you will be amazed by how fast it is, compared to the "vagrant ssh" middleman who has to load ruby and the vagrant machinery.

In the same vein for Ansible, you have to look at it from a slightly different way: how can I generate a SSH configuration file from an Ansible inventory (static or dynamic)?

Then you stumble upon projects such as https://github.com/selivan/ansible-ssh, that seems to do exactly what you want.

You just need to clone the repository, and run:

```
./ansible-ssh <node from inventory file>
```

It then forms the ssh command and launches it.

Comment: That looks very close to what I was looking for. Thanks, @marco.m. I'll try that out.

Comment: @jmartori you are welcome. If it fixes your problem, then please accept this answer.